# Combine 4 separate component R G B A in one texture

Tags: opengl, streaming, video-streaming, fbo

I'm developing a viewer for video-sequences. I use a scan-line based approach with
concurrent computation (fetching) for each row. Every row I get is separated in severals buffer (Channels) , namely R,G,B,A.

So imagine the problem as: I want to combine all my channels into one texture.
I have thought of doing it my-self, by allocating a temporary buffer in which I can upload the severals component, and give it to openGL with glTexSubImage2D(...), but the solution is very expensive...especially for image streaming!

Then I thought of multi-texturing: in short, make a separate texture (GL_LUMINANCE?) for every channel, and then combine it with a GLSL shader. I think this could work, unfortunately I have no experience in multi-texturing. Could somebody give me a link to a complete tutorial for multi-texturing please?

The last thing I could dig out of the internet is using a FBO, with a buffer texture. In
the buffer texture, use a buffer object with several indexes. But I couldn't get much more details about indexes in a buffer object, and if it would cater my needs.

Anyway, here is the final question : Is it possible to create one texture from 4 separate component (buffers) ? Or more precisely : How to draw 4 combined buffers, efficiently , in a context of video sequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multitexturing is indeed the way to go. Most important it allows you to have different formats for each channel, which allows for things like 4:2:2 subsampling or similar.

FBOs are drawing targets, not image sources, so not quite the right thing for you.

The basic idea behind multitexturing is, that there are a number of so called *texture units*, where the OpenGL call `glActiveTexture` selects the unit following calls of `glBindTexture` will work in. It requires some bookkeeping which texture is bound where, but its not very difficult.

In a fragment shader you can source samples from a texture through a so called *sampler uniform*. A sampler uniform is bound to a texture unit. A important pitfall is, that `glActiveTexture` takes as parameter `GL_TEXTURE0 + n` whereas the unit number passed to the sampler using `glUniformi` is just `n`.

It doesn't matter in which texture unit a texture is bound if you're just interested in uploading data. (Personally I'd like new versions of OpenGL to have a special texturing unit which can not be used as a source, but only allows binding of textures for image upload, and where there's no texture target precedence.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer datenwolf, I feel more sure of the way to go. Ps: Do you know any tutorial on multi-sampling in addition with fragment shaders ? Anyway, have a good day